# Python best practice for iterating until x successes?

Tags: python, while-loop, iteration

I apologize if this is answered elsewhere, but if so I haven't found it.

I want to iterate over an object and build a list of x items that meet my evaluation criteria. I want to stop iterating once I have reached my threshold number of items. I have tried doing this with a while loop and a counter, which I almost never see in Python, and I am now doing it with a for loop and a test condition at the beginning. What I am doing now works, but I am thinking there must be a better pattern, maybe instead using a generator that I run x number of times.

```
list_length = 25
list_results = []

for item in some_object:

    # test if list length condition met
    results_count = len(list_results)
    if results_count >= list_length:
        break

    # length condition not met, process some more
    if item == some_criteria:
        list_results.append(item)
```

The fact that I can find almost no examples of this is usually a pretty good indicator that I am doing it wrong - any insight into best practice would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, what about `itertools.islice`?

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> some_object = range(1000)
>>> good_values = (x for x in some_object if x % 5 == 0)
>>> keep = list(islice(good_values, 0, 25))
>>> len(keep)
25
```

This will work even if there aren't 25 to get:

```
>>> good_values = (x for x in some_object if x > 10**6)
>>> keep = list(islice(good_values, 0, 25))
>>> len(keep)
0
```

Comment: Why do you think `islice` is a better solution instead of the normal slicing [:25] (in this particular case ofc)?

Comment: @PaoloCasciello: what if `some_object` is long, and testing the criterion is slow?  There's no reason to have to keep doing work after you've found the first 25.  `some_object` might not even be materializable in the first place: it could be `itertools.count()`, for example.

Comment: @PaoloCasciello: `islice` works with generators, which this answer uses. You can't use `[:25]` on a generator.

Comment: @user2357112 ugh... right.. i completely forgot i can't use slice on gen.. sorry -_-'

Comment: @DSM: re your comment on some_object being long, doesn't good_values need to iterate through the entire some_object before slicing? Maybe I am reading it wrong. I would like to iteratively slice from some_object without having to completely iterate like I think good_values does. That would be great if possible (looking at the docs now).

Comment: @AlanS: the parentheses mean that it's a generator expression (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) in the tutorial), and so isn't evaluated instantly.  At the console, type `g = (x for x in range(100) if x % 5 == 0)` and then `print(g)`.  Then type `next(g)` a few times, and then `list(g)`.

Comment: @DSM: Thanks - I have only seen generators as functions with yield instead of return statements. Very cool. I will go through the tutorial - glad I asked!

Answer (score 3):

You can break once you've added the 25th item:

```
for item in some_object:
    if item == some_criteria:
        list_results.append(item)
        if len(list_results) >= 25:
            break
```

Anything more complicated seems premature optimization to me, unless there's a good reason to make it more complex.

Comment: Several great solutions - thanks! In my case, I am pulling data via a 3rd party API that is painfully slow, so I want to iterate as few cycles as possible (I don't want to iterate 1,000 or 1 million times to slice only 25 successes).

Comment: @AlanS: Note that the `islice` answer will also stop after 25 successes. You'll need to use a generator, though.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks - As mentioned in other comments, I am going to explore this more. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

reusing your variable names:

```
import itertools
itertools.islice( ( item for item in some_object if item == some_criteria ), list_length )
```